# tkinter window not open when using class

Tags: python, tkinter

The window now won't open. I've tried removing the import, and it doesn't help. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
class Login_window:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root-root
        self.root.title("Login")
        self.root.geometry("1550*800+0+0")
        if __name__=="__main__":
            root=tk()
            app=Login_window(root)
            app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't ever try to create an instance of `Login_window`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you‘re trying to subtract the root argument from the undefined variable `self.root`. Then you‘re calling the Tkinter module insted of the correct instance. This code should work:

from tkinter import *

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
class Login_window:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Login")
        self.root.geometry("1550*800+0+0")

if __name__=="__main__":
  root = Tk()
  app = Login_window(root)
  app.mainloop()
```